# Repeated Independent Events

Tags: probability, independence

Most of the problems from this section of my textbook are on this site, but this one is missing. I'd like the community to verify the answer for me, please.

> According to an advertising study, $15\%$ of television viewers who have seen a certain automobile commercial can correctly identify the actor who does the voice-over. Suppose that ten such people are watching TV and the commercial comes on. What is the probability that at least one of them will be able to name the actor? What is the probability that exactly one will be able to name the actor?

Here is my solution:

$P$(at least one viewer recognizes actor) $=$
$1 - P$(no viewers recognize actor) $=   
 1-0.85^{10}  = .803.$

$P$(only the first viewer recognizes actor) $ =   
 .15^1\cdot 0.85^9 = .0347.$

Multiply result by $10$ because there are $10$ possible ways to choose one viewer from a group of $10$ viewers, so
$P$(exactly one viewer recognizes actor) $ = .347$

> Bonus

$P$(only the first two viewers recognize actor) $=  
 .15^2\cdot 0.85^8 = .0061 .$ 
Multiply result by $45$ because that's the number of combinations of $2$ viewers from a group of $10$ viewers, so
$P$(exactly two viewers recognize actor) $ =  .276$.

Comment: Please add the answer which we shall verify or clarify your question.

Comment: The textbook didn't provide an answer for the problem (even number problem). I was hoping someone on this site could verify my solution.

Comment: You need to show *your* solution in order to have it verified.

Comment: Now I see that I'm supposed to include my solution in the question, not as an answer. I'll head to the penalty box now.

Comment: @DanBanaszak Your calculations look good for me, but one little advice: Your notation is not quite good. You write e. g. P(exactly one...) = $.0347$ and later P(exactly one ... ) =$.347$, which can't be true. The latter one is correct. The first probability should be P(only the first viewer recognizes actor) = $.0347$. Similar at your last results.

Comment: Thanks and good call. I revised the wording. Do you think you could say:  P(any given viewer recognizes the actor) and P(any given two viewers recognize the actor)?

Comment: @DanBanaszak That's not completely clear to me, but maybe it is also a problem with my English.

Comment: I'm glad you think the calculation worked out and thanks for cleaning up my notation. It's clearly my first time using MathJax. Take care!